# Paw and Auth0 audience

Tags: auth0, paw-app

For one reason or the other Auth0 expects an audience parameter in the header of your authentication. This means that you cannot just use the default oauth2 clientid/secret flow which is very annoying as you somehow have to first do a raw call to get your bearer and then reuse this bearer in the rest of your calls.

Is there an easy way to add this audience parameter to a rest call in Paw? 
This is the raw call I do in for example postman, before each call.

```
  const echoPostRequest = {
  url: 'https://[url].eu.auth0.com/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
  body: {
    mode: 'application/json',
    raw: JSON.stringify(
        {
            //Client name:  API
            client_id:'',
            client_secret:'',

            audience:'https://[url].eu.auth0.com/api/v2/',
            grant_type:'client_credentials'
        })
  }
};
```

Comment: Can't you just use the Auth and Custom settings to set your header as you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `audience` in the Authorization URL as a query parameter e.g.
`https://[url].eu.auth0.com/authorize?audience=https://[url].eu.auth0.com/api/v2/`